# Компилятор Clang не находит стандартные библиотеки в с++

Tags: c++, компиляция, clang

Я пытался скомпилировать свою программу через Clang на Windows 10 x64, однако он не находит iostream. Ставил Clang через exe файл. Вот сам код файла, который я пытался компилировать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
cout << "hello world";
return 0;
}
```

сама ошибка:

```
clang: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]
main.cpp:9:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Команда для компиляции:

```
clang main.cpp
```

Как мне добавить библиотеку iostream в Clang?

Comment: какая ОС, как ставили компилятор, как компилируете, какие ошибки получаете, зачем столько лишнего кода?

Comment: Там же первой строкой все четко написано...

Comment: что ты имеешь  в ввиду?

Comment: `clang: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]` - читайте еще раз

Comment: и что? Я не собираюсь устанавливать Visual Studio. Я бы хотел работать с Clang

Comment: Как вариант, можно ставить не всю Visual Studio, а только С++ тулчейн.

Comment: объясни что ты имеешь в виду

Comment: Кланг на винде не самодостаточен, ему нужна или Visual Studio или MinGW, чтобы брать оттуда стандартные библиотеки. Если хотите использовать MinGW, то проще поставить [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), и оттуда поставить и Clang, и MinGW. Их версия кланга настроена так, чтобы по умолчанию использовать их же MinGW, и все гарантированно будет работать из коробки.

Comment: Есть еще вариант - поставить MinGW отдельно, а оффициальную версию кланга каждый раз запускать с флагом `--target=x86_64-w64-mingw32` (это для 64-битного MinGW, для 32-битного - `--target=i686-w64-mingw32`). Если MinGW не в PATH, еще может быть нужен `--sysroot=путь/до/mingw`). Но я не представляю, зачем кому-то это делать, если есть msys2.